# Threaded compositing for producing iOS-like scrolling?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, scroll, compositing

What is threaded compositing?

It was referred to in a recent [Paul Irish Post](https://plus.google.com/113127438179392830442/posts/Kgk78sixgYp) as a means to produce iOS-like scrolling:

I searched chrome about:flags but wasn't able to find what Paul was referring to. I assume it has something to do with how elements are rendered but I'm interested in if/how compositing can be tackled programmatically (in JavaScript?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, threaded compositing is an experimental feature, and thus is [only available in the dev or canary channel](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.html). If you'd like to try this feature out, you can [download a Chrome build in the dev or canary channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).

About the feature itself, it is described as follows on `chrome://flags/`:

> Uses a secondary thread to perform web page compositing. This allows smooth scrolling, even when the main thread is unresponsive.

Comment: @avarnet, so it sounds its a property of the browser. Can you give some general advice as to how javascript/css programmers can ensure that they don't get into secondary threads and make their main threads unresponsive? Are you just talking bad recursion/for loops?

Comment: @timpeterson My understanding is that this secondary thread is only used "internally" by Chrome; it won't run any of your JavaScript, so you don't have to worry about having multiple parts of your code running in multiple threads.

Comment: @avarnet, thanks that helps clarify, nobody wants to do more coding so that's great!

Answer (score 2):

Tested this flag on this page, still scrolling freezes
http://romaxa.info/tests/scrolltest/layout3_busy_long.html

Works good on XUL firefox (Mobile version with multiprocess layers)

Comment: hi @romaxa, which phones have XUL Firefox? I've never heard of that before